excel interop automation through IIS
Disclaimer: I'm aware that Microsoft neither recommends nor supports using server-side automation for Office products. I don't have a choice. I need to migrate an old application to a new server environment and our developers won't complete their code migration for some time. I would love to move to something like ClosedXML or EPPlus in the short term but it's not up to me.
Disclaimer #2: I'm aware that there are many similar questions on the StackExchange network and at this point I've gone through more than I can count - unfortunately none of them have been able to help me.
--
That said, I have a Windows Server 2022 box with Office 365 installed, and IIS hosting a .NET application which uses the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel assembly to programmatically interact with Excel sheets. IIS is using anonymous authentication with the application pool identity. The app pool is likewise running with the application pool identity. The Excel DCOM application has been configured to run with the same identity, with all necessary permissions granted to the DCOM object.
When the application goes to do its thing, it immediately errors out with the following -

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

One of my issues is I'm struggling to understand which resource access is being denied to. I have set permissions on the Microsoft Excel Application in DCOM to allow access by the IIS application pool identity account, which is the account running the IIS worker process, and updated the DCOM identity to match. I have tried using other accounts for both the DCOM object and IIS as well, including various local user accounts, the local Administrator account, NETWORK SERVICE, and others, updating all permissions and identities to match - same result. Immediate access denied as above. Access denied to what?
Event viewer shows the following after each failure -

Unable to start a DCOM Server: {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}. The error:
"2147942405"
Happened while starting this command:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE /automation -Embedding

I have not been able to get much clarity on error "2147942405".
One exception to the above is when I configure IIS to use the IUSR account for its anonymous identity and configure the Excel DCOM application to run as the launching user. With this configuration, I can see an excel.exe process running under IUSR. However, the application simply hangs - no errors, nothing in event viewer, nothing anywhere as far as I can tell. Just spins indefinitely. The moment I change the DCOM identity to anything else - instant access denied error shown above, even when that identity has been granted all permissions on the DCOM object.
To top it off, this setup is functional on the Windows Server 2019 box currently hosting this application (the one we need to migrate off of) - IIS running with the application pool identity, anonymous authentication with the IUSR identity, and the Excel Application DCOM object using a separate local account. That same setup on the new server - access denied to... something.
--
One other thing to mention - the access denied error above refers to a CLSID of {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}. However, the id of the Microsoft Excel Application in the DCOM console is {00020812-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}. Looking through the registry, it seems like one points to the other so I'm not sure if this is something to be concerned about or just a red herring.
And actually one last thing - when running this application through Visual Studio using the built-in IIS Express (on the 2022 box), everything works. I can also successfully manipulate Excel sheets using DCOM through PowerShell. So I'm "assuming" there's probably nothing wrong with DCOM and probably something wrong with the IIS configuration.
I'd love to say that we can just hold off on the migration until we can get rid of this Excel interop garbage, but I don't think that's going to be an option.
Thanks for any help.
edit:
Also, setting the DCOM identity to "the interactive user" results in successful execution of the application. However, setting the DCOM identity to "this user" and specifying the exact same account results in the aforementioned access denied errors.

have not been able to get much clarity on error "2147942405". Hex: 0x80070005. when running this application through Visual Studio using the built-in IIS Express (on the 2022 box), everything works. Sounds like you need to connect the debugger to the IIS that is producing the error. You can also use Sysinternals Procmon to facilitate identification of the registry key where access is denied.

Ah good call on the hex to decimal - didn't realize that. I have been using procmon to help troubleshoot this but no luck yet. Another strange thing is setting the DCOM identity for Excel to "interactive user" works fine... but setting it to "this user" with the exact same account results in the same access denied errors.

I was not able to identify the source of the access denied errors. However, I found a functional workaround.
I created a permanent autologon as described here.
This is an interactive session, acting as a physical console login without a human or a "real" desktop, and allows the Excel COM object to run as the interactive user while simultaneously allowing the application to execute its code unattended. I'm still not clear on why the DCOM "interactive user" works while "this user" throws access denied errors, when the same account is being used in both scenarios ("this user" fails even when that user is interactively logged in at the time of execution).
Not ideal but nothing about this is ideal - at a minimum this should suffice until our developers can move away from Office interop.
